# jQuery AJAX POST method not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to execute the AJAX operation. the call is working fine but the problem I am having is that I am getting an empty string as a response. There is no error in the console. all I get is an empty string. Even when I change the dataType to `JSON`, I still get the same response.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data/saveCart.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    cartItem:item
  },
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['cartItem'])) {
  echo "AJAX successful";
} else {
  echo "AJAX failed";
}
```

Comment: Try stringify your data Object like: var obj = JSON.stringify(<your data>); and set it as your data in that Ajax call

Comment: Your if/else will echo something. So, question is maybe the ajax call is not hitting the right php? Or, the php code you have pasted is not exactly as it is in `saveCart.php`? What does your network tab show when the ajax requests a page (what is the php name, and what headers/response does it send/get)?

Comment: Take a look at the answers please.

Comment: Well it does show a successful call made to saveCart.php and the php code is exactly the same I pasted

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was caused by not `stringifying` your data.

```
var item = {
  toothbrush: {
    price: 1
  }  
};

$.ajax({
  url: "data/saveCart.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    cartItem: JSON.stringify( item )
  },
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried `stringifying` my data now it finally prints `AJAX failed` in the console(the response from `saveCart.php`) but what is the problem why the `$_POST['cartItem']` is not set?

Comment: Does the request throw any errors in the networking tab?

Comment: Are the request parameters set correctly? If so, the PHP file you are using has some flaws in it.